# I want to remove json itself after starting to new flutter project, how to do it?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

[image]

In json file:

```json
{
"modules": [

]}
```

How to remove the file? It's repeat every time I create flutter project.

Comment: Why do you care?  It's there because something is still wanting to look at it.

Comment: it shouldn't be happening only my flutter is the problem like that